# Passing Mat from OpenCV to Facedetector from MLkit

Tags: android, firebase, opencv, firebase-mlkit

For a personal application on an NVIDIA shield I'm using the MLKit from Firebase with the face detection functionality, but passing Mat from OpenCV doesn't really want to work.

In my android application I use a custom camera view made with OpenCV which creates returns a Mat on each frame it processes. On this process I'm checking each frame for a face.

The frist thing I tried is converting the Mat to Bitmap using the following code:

```java
public static Bitmap bitmapFromMat(Mat mRgba) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bitmap);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

After that I passed the bitmap to firebase which worked with the following code:

```java
FirebaseVisionImage fbImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);
fbDetector.detectInImage(fbImage) ....
```

This worked fine in the first 1 minute of running the application. After that the application started to lag badly and stopped working without any error message. In the run log I saw a message of not using bitmap with camera.

After that I was searching for a solution to convert the Mat to bytearray and bytebuffer but all the solutions I've tried were a fail.
Code creating the meta data:

```java
metadata = new FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.Builder()
                .setWidth(mFrame.width())
                .setHeight(mFrame.height())
                .setFormat(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21)
                .setRotation(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_0)
                .build();
```

(To be sure I changed the rotation to every single possibility and tested it)

Code I used to convert from Mat to bytearray:

```java
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) (mFrame.total() * mFrame.channels())];
        mFrame.get(0,0, bytes);

        FirebaseVisionImage fbImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromByteArray(bytes, metadata);
```

(what happend with this is that the face detection returns 0 faces)

Code I used to convert bitmap to bytebuffer:

```java
        int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);

        FirebaseVisionImage fbImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromByteBuffer(byteBuffer, metadata);
```

(what happend with this is that the face detection returns 0 faces)

What I expect is that a face is being detected every single frame, but sadly this is not the case. The current outcome is either enormous lag following with a crash or a detection of 0 faces.

I hope someone is able to help me with this problem!

Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In the JavaCameraView class you need to have your Mat function like this

```
 @Override
    public Mat rgba() {
       // Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);

        if (previewFormat == ImageFormat.NV21) {
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21, 4);
        }
        else if (previewFormat == ImageFormat.YV12) {
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGB_I420, 4);  // COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YV12 produces inverted colors
        }
        return mRgba;
    }
```

You will notice that the function initializeCamera has the ImageFormat YV12 and NV21... that's the Image Format that MLkit needs.

Then, on your face detector you will need to convert your Mat from RGBA2YUV like this:

```
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba,mRgba,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2YUV_YV12);

byte[] return_buff = new byte[(int) (mRgba.total() *
        mRgba.channels())];
mRgba.get(0, 0, return_buff);
```

your FirebaseVision builder need's to be like this

```
FirebaseVisionImageMetadata metadata = new FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.Builder()
        .setFormat(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.IMAGE_FORMAT_YV12)
        .setWidth(1920)   // 480x360 is typically sufficient for
        .setHeight(1080)  // image recognition
        .setRotation(0)
        .build();


image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromByteArray(return_buff,metadata);
```